# Should I provide consistency checks in the Huffman tree building algorithm for DEFLATE?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, deflate, validation

In RFC-1951 there is a simple algorithm that restores the Huffman tree from a list of code lengths, described following way:

```
     1)  Count the number of codes for each code length.  Let
         bl_count[N] be the number of codes of length N, N >= 1.

     2)  Find the numerical value of the smallest code for each
         code length:

            code = 0;
            bl_count[0] = 0;
            for (bits = 1; bits <= MAX_BITS; bits++) {
                code = (code + bl_count[bits-1]) << 1;
                next_code[bits] = code;
            }

     3)  Assign numerical values to all codes, using consecutive
         values for all codes of the same length with the base
         values determined at step 2. Codes that are never used
         (which have a bit length of zero) must not be assigned a
         value.

            for (n = 0;  n <= max_code; n++) {
                len = tree[n].Len;
                if (len != 0) {
                    tree[n].Code = next_code[len];
                    next_code[len]++;
                }
```

But there is no any data consistency checks in the algorithm. On the other hand is it obvious that the lengths list can be invalid. The length values, because of encoding in 4 bits can not be invalid, but, for example, there can be more codes than can be encoded for some code length.

What is the minimal set of checks that will provide data validation? Or such checks are not needed for some reason that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zlib checks that the list of code lengths is both complete, i.e. that it uses up all bit patterns, and that it does not overflow the bit patterns.  The one allowed exception is when there is a single symbol with length 1, in which case the code is allowed to be incomplete (The bit 0 means that symbol, a 1 bit is undefined).

This helps zlib reject random, corrupted, or improperly coded data with higher probability and earlier in the stream.  This is a different sort of robustness than what was suggested in another answer here, where you could alternatively permit incomplete codes and only return an error when an undefined code is encountered in the compressed data.

To calculate completeness, you start with the number of bits in the code `k=1`, and the number of possible codes `n=2`.  There are two possible one-bit codes.  You subtract from `n` the number of length 1 codes, `n -= a[k]`.  Then you increment `k` to look at two-bit codes, and you double `n`.  Subtract the number of two-bit codes.  When you're done, `n` should be zero.  If at any point `n` goes negative, you can stop right there as you have an invalid set of code lengths.  If when you're done `n` is greater than zero, then you have an incomplete code.

Comment: I am little bit confused here. Is a[] equal to bl_count[] from RFC-1951?

Comment: Well, I tested it and this way is really simple. It needed only 5 additional instructions in assembly. Anyway, should I handle the 1bit exception you mentioned? And why this exception is allowed?

Comment: It is allowed because the original PKZIP specification for the deflate format allows that in the case of a single distance code.  I consider this to be an error, since if there is only one possible code then you need zero bits to code it, not one.  However Phil Katz (the PK in PKZIP) decided to make it one bit and not zero bits.

Comment: This exception costs me more code than the general algorithm... :*( Anyway, thanks for the great help. :)

Comment: In terms of execution time you can wait to check for the exception until after you have determined that the code is incomplete.

Comment: Well, it is not actually big deal. I simply wanted to fit the code in 170 bytes, to have consistency check and still to build a real tree structure in order to speed the decoding later. Anyway, now I implemented it in 180 bytes and it is still pretty good for my goals.

Comment: In addition, I am allocating memory for the Huffman tree according to the assumption that the tree is full binary tree. Allowing incomplete trees will need more memory for the node structure and this way can lead to buffer overruns.

Comment: The only incomplete tree that should be allowed is one node for a single symbol with a one-bit code (0).  That should not lead you needing any more memory.

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is exactly what I made. BTW, the code for this procedure is finished and works as intended: **[Here](http://fresh.flatassembler.net/fossil/repo/fresh/artifact/1c64467e5a41a258?ln=41-188)**

Answer (score 1):

I think that checking that `next_code[len]` does not overflow past its respective bits is enough. So after `tree[n].Code = next_code[len];`, you can do the following check:

```
if (tree[n].Code & ((1<<len)-1) == 0)
    print(Error)
```

If `tree[n].Code & ((1<<len)-1)` reaches 0, it means that there are more codes of length `len` than they should, so the lengths list had an error in it.
On the other hand, if every symbol of the tree is assigned a valid (unique) code, then you have created a correct Huffman tree.

EDIT: It just dawned on me: You can simply make the same check at the end of step one: You just have to check that `bl_count[N] <= 2^N - SUM((2^j)*bl_count[N-j])` for all `1<=j<=N` and for all `N >=1` (If a binary tree has `bl_count[N-1]` leaves in level `N-1`, then it cannot have more than `2^N - 2*bl_count[N-1]` leaves in level `N`, level 0 being the root).

This guarantees that the code you create is a prefix code, but it does not guarantee that it is the same as the original creator intended. If for example the lengths list is invalid in a way that you can still create a valid prefix code, you cannot prove that this is the Huffman code, simply because you do not know the frequency of occurence for each symbol.

Comment: Yes, this approach seems to be OK. But isn't it possible to move this check to the stage 2 or stage 1 of the algorithm. It is not so important, but in stage 3 I already have allocated memory for the tree and on error have to free it.

Comment: You can do it also at the end of step 1, check my Edit

Comment: Hm, this sum resembles a little what is done in the loop of stage 2... I have to meditate a little on it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that there is no input that will cause your code to execute illegal or undefined behavior, such as indexing off the end of an array, because such illegal inputs might be used to attack your code.

In my opinion, you should attempt to handle illegal but not dangerous inputs as gracefully as possible, so as to inter-operate with programs written by others which may interpret the specification in a different way than you have, or which have made small errors which have only one plausible interpretation. This is the Robustness principle - you can find discussions of this starting at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle.

Comment: Well yes, these are common, well known rules. But how in the best way to apply these rules to the specific code from the question?